# Mysterious space added in matrix-like environments

Tags: bug, status-declined, mathjax

[image]
[image]
Here are two screenshots taken from [3D rotation matrix with zero determinant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3139308/) and [Simplify this expression for the relative condition number of $f(x,y) := [ x^y, x + y ]^T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3134228/). It can be seen that an extra space is added between the left bracket and the matrix body. I have also tested some other matrix-like environments such as `pmatrix` and `vmatrix`, and there is always such a space added next to the left delimiter.

Is this due to some updates of MathJax or my browser? I am using Internet Explorer 11. Thanks.

---

**Edit:** This anomaly occurs when the renderer is HTML-CSS but disappears when the renderer is common HTML, preview HTML or SVG. The versions of related scripts are:

`MathJax.js v2.7.5

TeX Input Jax v2.7.5
HTML-CSS Output Jax v2.7.5
PreviewHTML Output Jax v2.7.5
mml Element Jax v2.7.5`

Comment: You should also say which MathJax renderer you are using (this is site-specific, and can be set separately on Math.SE and Meta Math.SE).  Right-click on a MathJax rendered expression and using the `Math Settings > Math Renderer` submenu to report the current selection (or change it, to see if your results vary).

Comment: I don't see that at home, I don't see it in my office. (Both are Chromium on Linux.) I think that IE11 is quite outdated. Try a different browser to find out.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this in other browsers, so my money's on IE11 doing something funky. It's just about at the tail end of its life and the issue looks to be fairly minor, so we're not going to be addressing it at this time.